# Check current month of year if passed show next year

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, what I want to achieve is to somehow check the current month against the current year (say August 2020), if it is passed I want to display the following year (say August 2021). Something like this code I guess. I know it's not correct just wanted to show roughly what I'm after. Thank Jason

```
var d = new Date();
if (getFullYear > now) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getFullYear() + 1);
}else   
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getFullYear();
}
```

With the output being: **August `<span id="demo"></span>`** <-- The year

Comment: Where do you specify what Month to test against?

Comment: _"check the current month against the current year"_ - What? How can the _current_ month be _past_ the current year (or itself)? o.O

Comment: @Andreas he is probably trying to compare current date (month and year) with a specific date. So if he has august 2020 and now we are in september he wants to show august 2021 (probably for a booking feature)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

```js
const d = new Date();
const AUGUST = 7; // starts from 0

if (d.getMonth() > AUGUST) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getFullYear() + 1;
} else {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so let's say your month to test against in some variable.

```
const monthToCheck = 8; // or August and you converted into number 
const now = new Date(); // current dateTime stamp

// to check with current month plus one since it stats 0-11
if(monthToCheck >= now.getMonth() + 1) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = now.getFullYear();
} else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = now.getFullYear() + 1;
}
```

Or one-liner code

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = monthToCheck >= new Date().getMonth() + 1 ? new Date().getFullYear() : new Date().getFullYear() + 1 ;
```